# Retrieving request information form ServiceNow via API

Tags: rest, servicenow

Within our ServiceNow installation we have created a simple new Request form with two text input values. The form looks something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Get new Computer-request                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| model: <text input field>                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| organization: <text input field>                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

When a new request has been created using this form, we can retrieve all
relevant information using the ServiceNow table API, by querying the following tables:

- sc_req_item
- sc_item_option_mtm
- sc_item_option
- sc_cat_item

When issuing these REST calls we have to use several filters to navigate from one table to another and to only get the most recent items and only the request items within our service catalog category.

Ideally, we would like to save the entire request (timestamp, user, input values) as a JSON String within a single table. This way, we would only have to query this single table to retrieve all relevant information for a request.

Does ServiceNow support generating/saving a single JSON file from request form?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading about scripted REST Apis as suggested by Joey's answer, I have created some code to do the table joining and filtering on ServiceNow.

The code is here: https://github.com/1123/ServiceNowRequestsApi

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to be able to make a single request to the instance which gives you all the details of the request (across tables), you may be better off defining a custom [Scripted REST api](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/custom-web-services/concept/c_CustomWebServices.html).

You'd write a script to define the JSON response you want, and then just call that API instead of the standard table query APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does sound like a viable solution. But how does this work in the background? Does the scripted REST API itself do multiple calls to the table api to then present the information to consumer? Also would this allow to store a single JSON object for a request in the CMDB?

Comment: You make a single call to your custom scripted REST endpoint, and it returns a single payload based entirely on how you write your custom Scripted REST configuration. Within your script, you would likely make multiple GlideRecord calls, appending to the `response` object to build your JSON response. Here's an example: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/custom-web-services/reference/r_ScriptedRESTExampleStreamVsLO.html

Comment: Thanks @Joey, followed your advice and posted an answer with the code.

Comment: One more question: I would like to develop my javascript code locally instead of through the ServiceNow Web Interface. Is there a way of posting my code that makes up the Scripted API to ServiceNow?